# How to select overlapping date ranges in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table with the following columns :
sID, start_date and end_date

Some of the values are as follows:

```
1   1995-07-28  2003-07-20 
1   2003-07-21  2010-05-04 
1   2010-05-03  2010-05-03 
2   1960-01-01  2011-03-01 
2   2011-03-02  2012-03-13 
2   2012-03-12  2012-10-21 
2   2012-10-22  2012-11-08 
3   2003-07-23  2010-05-02
```

I only want the 2nd and 3rd rows in my result as they are the overlapping date ranges.

I tried this but it would not get rid of the first row. Not sure where I am going wrong?

```
select a.sID from table a
inner join table b 
on a.sID = b.sID
and ((b.start_date between a.start_date and a.end_date)
and (b.end_date between a.start_date and b.end_date ))
order by end_date desc
```

I am trying to do in SQL Server

Answer (score 7):

One way of doing this reasonably efficiently is

```
WITH T1
     AS (SELECT *,
                MAX(end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY sID ORDER BY start_date) AS max_end_date_so_far
         FROM   YourTable),
     T2
     AS (SELECT *,
                range_start = IIF(start_date <= LAG(max_end_date_so_far) OVER (PARTITION BY sID ORDER BY start_date), 0, 1),
                next_range_start = IIF(LEAD(start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY sID ORDER BY start_date) <= max_end_date_so_far, 0, 1)
         FROM   T1)
SELECT SId,
       start_date,
       end_date
FROM   T2
WHERE  0 IN ( range_start, next_range_start );
```

if you have an index on `(sID, start_date) INCLUDE (end_date)` this can perform the work with a single ordered scan.

Comment: Wow, works perfectly fine! Thankyou! However is there any way to do it without using the partition by functions/ simpler query?

Comment: @koala - this is optimised for performance not simplicity of syntax

Answer (score 6):

Your logic is not totally correct, although it almost works on your sample data.  The specific reason it fails is because `between` includes the end points, so any given row matches itself.  That said, the logic still isn't correct because it doesn't catch this situation:

```
 a-------------a
      b----b
```

Here is correct logic:

```
select a.*
from table a
where exists (select 1
              from table b
              where a.sid = b.sid and
                    a.start_date < b.end_date and
                    a.end_date > b.start_date and
                    (a.start_date <> b.start_date or  -- filter out the record itself
                     a.end_date <> b.end_date
                    )
             )
order by a.end_date;
```

The rule for overlapping time periods (or ranges of any sort) is that period 1 overlaps with period 2 when period 1 starts before period 2 ends and period 1 ends after period 2 starts.  Happily, there is no need or use for `between` for this purpose.  (I strongly discourage using `between` with date/time operands.)

I should note that this version  does not consider two time periods to overlap when one ends on the same day another begins.  That is easily adjusted by changing the `<` and `>` to `<=` and `>=`.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/12660) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: My table has many other sIDs. I tried running your query and filtered it on where sID=1 and it still giving me the same result.

Comment: @koala . . . Right.  You don't have a unique id identifying each row, so normally there would be `and a.id <> b.id`.  I added similar logic based on the start and end dates.

Comment: Now when I don't filter on sID=1, it only gives me those 2 rows and not any overlapping date ranges for any other sID

Comment: @koala . . . Nothing in the answer filters to `sID = 1`.  You must have something else wrong with your query.  I included a SQL Fiddle to show that it works.

Comment: You're right, works now! sorry about that and thanks! Can you please explain me the logic behind "a.start_date <> b.start_date or  
                     a.end_date <> b.end_date"

Comment: Also, based on the dates in question now, the query won't give 2003-07-23  2010-05-02

Comment: @koala . . . If you want overlapping ranges ignoring `sid`, then remove that condition from the subquery.  Based on your original question, the assumption that you want them within an `sid` is very reasonable, especially because you have that in *your* query.  Otherwise, the stated row doesn't overlap with anything else.