# Determine max number of overlapping DATETIME ranges

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, range, overlap

I got a table with some `DATETIME` ranges, something like

```
id | start               | end
----------------------------------------------
1  | 2011-12-18 16:00:00 | 2011-12-18 17:00:00
2  | 2011-12-19 08:00:00 | 2011-12-19 10:00:00
3  | 2011-12-19 11:00:00 | 2011-12-19 13:00:00
4  | 2011-12-19 12:00:00 | 2011-12-19 14:00:00
5  | 2011-12-19 13:00:00 | 2011-12-19 15:00:00
6  | 2011-12-19 13:00:00 | 2011-12-19 14:00:00
7  | 2011-12-20 13:00:00 | 2011-12-20 14:00:00
```

So for day 2011-12-19 the ranges spans like this:

```
8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15
<-------->
               <-------->
                    <-------->
                         <-------->
                         <---->
```

The goal is, when inserting new record, to find the max number of overlapping ranges already present: i.e.: when inserting the new range `2011-12-19 12:00:00 - 2011-12-19 15:00:00` i would like to receive `3`, because the max number of overlapping ranges is 3, from 13:00 to 14:00.

Since now i managed to have this

```
select
    count(*) as cnt
from
    mytable as p
where
    ( # check if new renge overlap existings ones
        (@start >= start and @start < end)
        or
        (@end > start and @end <= end)
    )
    or
    ( # check if existing range is included by new one
        start between @start and @end
        and
        end between @start and @end
    )
```

But this return `4` because it detects all ranges except the first, but is wrong.

I already found

- [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)
- [How to select overlapping date ranges in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49836518/how-to-select-overlapping-date-ranges-in-sql)
- [Checking a table for time overlap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571538/checking-a-table-for-time-overlap)

But all these questions are slightly different.

I'm on MysQL 5.7, but upgrading to 8 is possibile if necessary.

Comment: Your sample data and expected out do not match. Below is a DateTime overlap query.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Why example data and expected output do not match?

Comment: I believe that you have an error in your example: you want to insert a new range for 19-12 right?

Comment: @RadimBača Yes, i didn't get very clear about this, the new example range would be `2011-12-19 12:00:00 - 2011-12-19 15:00:00`

Comment: @RadimBača as said at the end of the question i'm currently on MySQL 5.7 but upgrading to 8 is not a big deal if necessary

Comment: @CetinBasoz Ok, i found i wrote the wrong day for the new range (20 instead of 19)

Comment: OK your expected output still doesn't match. Check the query below I gave, it returns correct output which should be 4 (there are 4 overlapping ranges, not 3).

Comment: @CetinBasoz I still not getting where do i have 4 ranges overlapping, may you pinpoint the time start/end?

Comment: All the rows with id 3,4,5 6 overlaps with the range given.

Comment: @CetinBasoz yeah, but 3 doesn't overlap 5 nor 6, so the max number of simultaneously overlapping ranges is not 4 but 3, in the time range that span 
 from 13:00 to 14:00

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer is for MySQL 8.0 that contains window functions. The core of the solution will be the following query that finds a number of overlapping intervals for every interesting interval in the data:

```
select t2.startDt, t2.endDt, count(*) overlaps_count
from
(
    select lag(t1.dt) over (order by t1.dt) startDt, t1.dt endDt
    from
    (
        select startt dt from data
        union
        select endt dt from data
    ) t1
) t2
join data on t2.startDt < data.endt and t2.endDt > data.startt
group by t2.startDt, t2.endDt
```

[**DBFiddle DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=322e6ef202653e51c545551c9088ebce)

Once you have this result (let call it Overlap table) then you may easily find the maximum for an input interval as follows

```
with Overlap as
(
   -- the query above
)
select max(overlaps_count)
from Overlap 
where @start < endDt and @end > startDt
```

Comment: Yeah, this work correctly, but instead of making another super-query as you said wouldn't it the same to simply add a `where` clause in the original one just to filter the ranges that fall inside the new one?

Comment: or even better, adding the `where` clause in the most inner `union`ed selects?

Comment: @fudo I'm not sure about the first interval since it will contain null instead of DateTime. I believe that some null handling is needed even in my solution for the first interval and then you can put the condition into the most nested subquery. Best

Comment: do you mean in the select where you used `lag()`? yes, this record would have `null` as startDT but endDT would coincide with the start of incoming range, so i think it would be discarded (as information) because concerning a range i'm not interested in

Comment: @fudo true! so in such case you can move the '@start < endDt and @end > startDt' condition into the `Overlap` query.

Comment: I just noticed you referenced table alias `t1` in the main query in both `select` ad `group by` statement, you should correct it with alias `t2`; I dindn't noticed it before because I rearrenged your query to suit my specific use case

Answer (score -1):

Considering start and end would never be same:

```
select
    count(*) as cnt
from
    mytable as p
where
    # check if new renge overlap existings ones
        (@start < end and @end > start);
```

Comment: I think this will also return 4? Because it will not get the *maximum* number of overlapping ranges, but all overlapping ranges, right?

Comment: @ChatterOne, what does "maximum number of overlapping ranges" mean? How is it different than the number of overlapping ranges?

Comment: look at the example, you'll see that the overlapping ranges are `[11-13, 12-14]` and `[12-14, 13-15, 13-14]`. With your query you'll get 4 as a result because if any range overlaps with any other range, that will count. But if you want to know the maximum amount of ranges that overlap with each other, that's a different query. In this case the number is 3 because of the `[12-14, 13-15, 13-14]` values.

Comment: @ChatterOne, sorry I don't understand what you mean. There are 4 overlapping ranges there.

Comment: Yes, there are 4, but they're not all overlapping with each other. The range `11-13` is overlapping only with `12-14`. It is not, for example, overlapping with `13-15`. In total, there are two ranges that overlap with each other and another three that overlap with each other.

Comment: @ChatterOne, appearantly I missed your comment. There are 4 overlapping ranges there. 13-15 is an overlapping one too. It overlaps 12-14 and 13-14.